# SQLAlchemy update rows based on key:value like queries?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using the SQLAlchemy session to handle some updates to the database.
I am having two lists:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

values = [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

I want to set the value of `keys[0]` to be set to `values[0]`, and so on. From what I am used to do, this would be the solution:

```
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    db.session.query(Table).filter(Table.key == key).update(value: value)
```

But this obviously would need 5 seperate SQL queries.
Now, unfortunately I am neither a pro in SQL nor SQLAlchemy.

Is there any operation that allows me to just submit two same-length lists, and SQLAlchemy optimizes it itself, something like this?:

```
db.session.query(Table).filter(Table.key == keys).update(value: values)
```

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [case expression](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Case) inside `update()` if you need 1 query. Here is an example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import case
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///example.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
app.app_context().push()


class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, primary_key=True, )
    value = db.Column(db.Integer())


db.create_all()
data = {1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8, 4: 9, 5: 0}
for key in data.keys():
    db.session.add(Example(value=key))

db.session.commit()
print('before update: ')
for record in Example.query.all():
    print(f'id = {record.id}, value = {record.value}')


db.session.query(Example).filter(Example.value.in_(tuple(data.keys()))).update({
    'value': case(
        [(Example.value == k, v) for k, v in data.items()], # values map from dict
        else_=Example.value,  # default value
    )
})

db.session.commit()
print('after update: ')
for record in Example.query.all():
    print(f'id = {record.id}, value = {record.value}')
```

See logs:

```
before update:
id = 1, value = 1
id = 2, value = 2
id = 3, value = 3
id = 4, value = 4
id = 5, value = 5
...
# 1 UPDATE with CASE-WHEN-ELSE
UPDATE example SET value=CASE WHEN (example.value = ?) THEN ? WHEN (example.value = ?) THEN ? WHEN (example.value = ?) THEN ? WHEN (example.value = ?) THEN ? WHEN (example.value = ?) THEN ? ELSE example.value END WHERE example.value IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
...
after update: 
id = 1, value = 6
id = 2, value = 7
id = 3, value = 8
id = 4, value = 9
id = 5, value = 0
```